# How to use this pipe in angular 5 dynamically?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe, angular2-ngmodel

I am using pipe in my angular Application to filter options values based on search input given by user. This Filter is used at the field level of a form which is dynamically generated using ngFor loop and based on json response.

I am able to use the pipe concept to filter the value for a standalone single input but when I use it multiple times using Ngfor Loop like the below code, It doesn't work perfectly.

```
 // formdata is coming as of json response from a http request
<div *ngFor="let input1 of formdata.formfields">   


 <mat-select placeholder="Select something" [formControlName]="input1.field_name">
               <ngx-mat-select-search [(ngModel)]="searchText" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Select {{input1.title}}"></ngx-mat-select-search>

                // here I am using 'fitleroptions' pipe after ngFor and passing searchText ngmodel input binding  

             <mat-option *ngFor="let opt_value of input1.enumNameGroups |  filteroptions : searchText; let i = index" value={{input1.value}}>{{opt_value}}</mat-option>
       </mat-select>

    // other input types like file, text etc....

</div>
```

This gives me output like this.

[image]

Now the problem is that searchText assigned to ngmodel can not be used more then once as it is bounded to only one input and if I do so, it is affecting the other inputs also.

How to pass [(ngmodel)] ="some_variable" and then assign it to   filteroptions : "some_variable" so that they are bounded to only one selection input???

So the problem can be also expressed as how to pass dynamic ngmodel name and assign that name to  pipe parameters ?

This is the filteroptions pipe I am using .

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filteroptions'
})
export class FilterOptionsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if(!items) return [];
    if(!searchText) return items;
searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
return items.filter( it => {

        console.log("got item array here",items);
     return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
   }
}
```

Comment: If you ask advice for a pipe, maybe you should post the code of the said pipe ...

Comment: Hey, thanks for reminding me. I was really missing this code in my own asked question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're seeing is basically due to all `ngx-mat-select-search` inputs being two-way bound to the same field, `searchText`. You can easily work around this by introducing a template variable for your filter.

```
<ngx-mat-select-search ngModel #filter="ngModel" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Select {{input1.title}}"></ngx-mat-select-search>
<mat-option *ngFor="let opt_value of input1.enumNameGroups |  filteroptions : filter.value; let i = index" value={{input1.value}}>{{opt_value}}</mat-option>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<mat-select 
 placeholder="Owner" 
 [(ngModel)]="criteriaOwner" 
 name="ownerId" 
 required>
 <ngx-mat-select-search ngModel 
    #filter="ngModel" 
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
    [placeholderLabel]="'Find owner...'" 
    [noEntriesFoundLabel]="'No matching owner found'" >
 </ngx-mat-select-search>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of criteriaOwners | filterByProperty: 
      ['name',filter.value]; let i = index" [value]="item">
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="8px" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
            <div>
                {{item.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>

/*Write pipe like below.*/

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterByProperty'
})
export class FilterByPropertyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(list: any[], args?: any): any {
    if (!list || !args) {
      return list;
    }

    var columnName = args[0];
    var columnValue = args[1];

    return list.filter(listItem => ('' + listItem[columnName]).toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(columnValue.toString().toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="searchText">
<div *ngFor="let item of items | searchFilter:'id,name':searchText">{{item.name}}</div>
```

> pipeFilter.ts

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'searchFilter'
})

export class SearchFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(value, keys: string, term: string) {

    if (!term) return value;
    return (value || []).filter(x => keys.split(',').some(key => x.hasOwnProperty(key) && new RegExp(term, 'gi').test(x[key])));

  }
}
```